# Android DatePicker's date saving and loading

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I'm trying to save a `Datepicker`'s date into a file, and when opening the app read it back from last time and set the date on it accordingly (if it is the first time and no file was saved already, set it to Jan 1 2000). All widgets such as editText, names, gender, etc work correctly, except `DatePicker`.

For some reasons it doesn't work. Can someone help with that? There is no concern on the file IO part; probably there are some `Calendar`/`Date` compatibility issues I guess.

When loading:

```
Date BD=new Date(2000,0,1);
        // Loading (w/o exception handling code):
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput(fileName);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Object[] formData = (Object[]) is.readObject();
            is.close();
            fis.close();

            // parse data from array
        BD=(Date) formData[0];
//there are other fields as well

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO if for the first time- No data file exists
        // sets initial default value
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }

    //set value for BD
    final DatePicker BDDatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePickerBD);
    BDDatePicker.updateDate(BD.getYear(), BD.getMonth(), BD.getDate());
```

And for saving:

```
    final DatePicker BDdatePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePickerBD);
    Date BD= getDateFromDatePicker(BDdatePicker);
    Object [] formData=new Object [7];

    formData [0]=BD;


    //Saving (w/o exception handling code):
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = this.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(formData);
            fos.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted everything to `Calendar` and avoided `Date`'s deprecated methods. It was fixed (`Date.getYear()` gives a two-digit `YY` that should be added with 1900).